# Limit access to a single project while using the 2-Legged authentication method

Tags: permissions, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

One of our backend automation tools uses the [Data Management API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/overview/) to access files in ACC projects.
Since it is a backend process, fully unattended, we are using the client-credentials grant type (aka [2-Legged authentication method](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/)).
This is great, however it does not seem to be possible to restrict the access of the "ACC system" user to only specific projects.

I assume that in order to control permissions, a "service user" must be introduced and granted the specific permissions. Does it mean that [3-Legged authentication](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) shall be used? How to achieve then a fully automated unattended process?

Comment: Yes, there are some ACC endpoints only support 3LO, but can you tell me which ACC endpoints you are trying to use and not work with 2LO?

Comment: @ZhongWu Let's say projects/:project_id/items/:item_id for example. It supports both 2LO and 3LO. How can an unattended automation using this endpoint, while at the same time limiting access to a given project? If I use 2LO, all projects in the hub are visible. Not sure how to use 3LO if no user is around.

Comment: Hi Oli, not sure if I understand correctly, but my question is how can a project has no member? A project should always has at least a project admin, right? Also, you can use account admin user to perform the endpoint.

Comment: @ZhongWu Where did I say that I am dealing with projects without users? I have a [deamon app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-daemon-overview) with no user logged in. So we are talking about 2LO. BUT... How to restrict access of this app so that it can only access certain projects and NOT all projects? Is this clearer?

Comment: oh, sorry, I guess I misunderstand your issue, I get your point, will make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to find a way that Account Admin can provide granular access to the integrated App, which means the App can be only have limited access to some projects, right? Unfortunately, this is not supported currently, but we do understand the request and it's already logged as a wish from https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2019/06/15/bim-360-acc-api-known-issues-and-wishes/ as follow:

**BIMAPI-96:  “As an owner of BIM 360 account, we need a way to provide more consistent, granular controls when giving access to 3rd party apps”**

For now, as you said, the workaround to make limited access to some projects may go with 3 Legged Access, but you need to log in at least once, once logged, you can use the refresh token to automate refresh the access token without user login again, but the new refresh token will expire in 15 days.

I understand this is not an ideal solution, and as you said, some endpoint may only support 2legged token, and at least one time login is required, that's the limitation.

Hope it answers your question.